# Calling "which program" from Python with os.system or subprocess doesn't return path

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, system-calls

I'm using Python Version 2.7.10 with macOS Sierra 10.12.16 and Xcode 8.3.3.
I want to call latex from Python. **os.system('latex myFile.tex')** does not work because the complete path is needed. So I tried to get the path with the **which program** command.

```
import os
import subprocess

batcmd = '/usr/bin/which latex'
thePath = os.system(batcmd)
print("The path: "+str(thePath))

p = subprocess.Popen([batcmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
print(p.stdout.read())
```

The results I get from both variations are:

```
he path: 256

Program end

with exit code: 0
```

The system command delivers the number 256. The subprocess command derives an empty line. Other system calls like ls or dir work fine.

How can I get the path of a program with Python?

Answer (score 2):

The path var is included in my custom bin dirs, including Latex.

import os

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + '/usr/local/.......'

print(os.getenv("PATH"))

Comment: It should be assumed that the path unknown.

Comment: the usr/local/texlive/... is where it resides on my system along with the other included executables that come with texlive....